# Uptating angular version 12 to 13 in a library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, package.json

How can I upgrade my library from using angular 12 to 13
I'm trying to do

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli @angular/material
```

but it is only updating the project's package.json not the library's
[package.json files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZx4H.png)

library package.json:

```
   "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~12.2.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.9",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^12.0.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.20",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mat-contenteditable": "^9.1.0",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^10.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-permissions": "^8.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.1.3",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.3",
    "ts-file-parser": "^0.0.12",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^31.1.0"
  },
```

project package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/cdk": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/common": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/core": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/forms": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/material": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.2",
"@angular/router": "~13.3.2",
"ngx-toastr": "^14.2.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

},

And how can I know the peerDependencies?

Comment: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=12.0-13.0 go through this guide it will help to upgrade angular

Comment: In this guid they are using npx instaed of ng update, I guess it does the same and it's not working for me.
it works perfectly tho on the library's project @Abru007

Comment: @Adam did you ever find an answer? Or did you just do it manually by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to start the upgrade process in the right directory if you have many modules. Follow the online step-by-step guide https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=12.0-13.0 If needed delete existing node_modules and packageLock.json

Comment: `Ng update` on both directories is updating only the package.json on the library project not the library.

Comment: Start upgrade in `C:/user/library` not `C:/user/library/project`

Comment: yeah this is the problem. upgrading in both directories only upgrading c:/user/library/project/package.json
 no matter where I start the upgrade.